# how do I redraw overlays on a map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have a map that creates paths and stores them in a DB.  When the app is reloaded any saved paths are loaded again as a overlay   It works fine until I zoom in and I see that they don't resize properly.   How can I force a redraw to correct the size.    I included a screen shot of what I'm seeing.

[image]

Here is a sample of my code.   It draws subpaths for each point.  Similar to a breadcrump following the users location.  It's in a custom overlap class and called in

```
-(void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
          zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{


 for (int io=0;io<OverlayList.count;io++){
        CrumbPath *crumbs = [OverlayList objectAtIndex:io];

            NSMutableArray *colors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
            UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
            int speedcolor;
            UIColor *currentColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:256/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
            UIColor *NewcurrentColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:256/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

            [colors addObject:(id)[color CGColor]];

            for (int i=0;i<crumbs.pointCount;i++){
                NSInteger CurrentSpeed=crumbs.pointSpeed[i];
                speedcolor=255-((int)CurrentSpeed*3);

                if (speedcolor<2){
                    speedcolor=1;
                }

                CGMutablePathRef subpath = CGPathCreateMutable();
                CGPoint point = [self pointForMapPoint:crumbs.points[i]];
                if (i==0){
                    CGPathMoveToPoint(subpath, nil, point.x, point.y);
                    CGPathRelease(subpath);
                } else {

                    CGPoint prevPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:crumbs.points[i-1]];
                    CGPathMoveToPoint(subpath, nil, prevPoint.x, prevPoint.y);
                    CGPathAddLineToPoint(subpath, nil, point.x, point.y);

                    CGFloat lineWidth = MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(zoomScale);

                    CGFloat gradientLocation[2] = {0,1};
                    CGContextSaveGState(context);

                    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

                    CGPoint gradientStart = prevPoint;
                    CGPoint gradientEnd = point;
                    CGGradientRef gradient;

                    NewcurrentColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:speedcolor/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

                    NSMutableArray *colors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
                    UIColor *color;
                    [colors addObject:(id)[currentColor CGColor]];
                    color = NewcurrentColor;
                    [colors addObject:(id)[color CGColor]];

                    gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (CFArrayRef)colors, gradientLocation);


                    CGPathRef pathToFill = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(subpath, NULL, lineWidth, kCGLineCapRound, kCGLineJoinBevel, 0);
                    CGContextAddPath(context, pathToFill);

                    //NSLog(@"%f",lineWidth);

                    CGContextClip(context);//<--clip your context after you SAVE it, important!
                    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, gradientStart, gradientEnd, kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation);

                    CGContextRestoreGState(context);//<--Don't forget to restore your context.

                    currentColor = NewcurrentColor;
                    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
                    CGPathRelease(pathToFill);
                    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
                    CGPathRelease(subpath);

                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: We could use a bit more information on how the path is drawn in the first place. It would be best if you show some drawing-code.

Comment: Good point.  I edited my original.

Comment: So you're not using the MKPolyline? If you did that the path would get redrawn by the map view every time and be smooth at every step.

Comment: No, It's a customer overlay.  I did notice whenever I add a new overlay they are all redrawn properly.  Is there someone to do the sam thing without adding a new overlay to get the same affect?

Comment: That was suppose to say "custom" not "customer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that since you are using `-drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:`, you would also need to use `–setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:zoomScale:` in response to zooming your map (via delegate callbacks). Then your renderer will get called again to update its draws.